# Duplicate object in django, also duplicate child objects (related objects)

Tags: django, django-models

I want to learn how to copy an object but also copy the object referencing to that object.

As an example (simplified):
Model 1: **version**

- id
- name

Model 2: **file**

- id
- file name
- file contents
- foreign key pointing to version

Relationship: One version can have multiple files

So one software version can have multiple files. 
I want to duplicate a complete version.
Currently I have the following:

```
def duplicate_version(request,id, MAC_address):
    new_version = Version.objects.get(pk=id)
    new_version.pk = None
    new_version.save()

    new_files = File.objects.get(version_id=id)  <-- here I get the error
    new_id = new_version.id
    new_files.version_id = new_id
    new_files.save()
    return get_all_versions(request, MAC_address)
```

I understand how to copy an object and change the id (=None).
But how do I manage to duplicate all the related files?

Error I get: 
**Exception Value:** get() returned more than one File -- it returned 2!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you should probably read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/dn/2.0/topics/db/queries/). The `get()` method returns only one object. What you need is the `filter()` method to get a queryset.

Second, as you will have a queryset you cant just do `new_files.version_id = new_id`. If your field is a foreign key, try something like below. If its a many to many, just do `new_version.file_set.add(new_files)`:

```
def duplicate_version(request,id, MAC_address):
    new_version = Version.objects.get(pk=id)
    new_version.pk = None
    new_version = new_version.save()
    new_files = File.objects.filter(version_id=id)
    new_files.update(version_id=new_version.id)
    return get_all_versions(request, MAC_address)
```

Comment: Then just use the update method like in the code I posted.

Comment: @ Mehdi B Ok thank you. I added "new_files.save()" as is assume it is stil needed?

Comment: queryset doesnt have a save method

Comment: Just use the sample code I posted. If you use update() you dont need save().Again, save is for a single object, like get()

Comment: The code changed the foreign key of the new files. But it doesn't duplicate them

Comment: Oh I didnt understand from the code you posted you also wanted to duplicate thm. Please consider accepting my answer and upvote as it solved your first error and seem to have been useful.

Comment: Yes that's the way.

Comment: This way is not working properly in Django 4.x.  Peter's method works fine.

Answer (score 3):

```
def duplicate_version(request, pk, MAC_address):
    new_version = Version.objects.get(pk=pk)
    new_version.pk = None
    new_version.modification_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    new_version.save()

    new_files = File.objects.filter(version_id=pk)
    for file in new_files:
        file.version_id = new_version.pk
        file.pk = None
        file.save()
    return get_all_versions(request, MAC_address)
```